# Is it possible to have one common session in SPA and Django while using different domains?

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework, cross-domain, single-page-application

scenario:

> user logs in **domain-A** serving SPA (e.g Angular authenticating via
>   API to Django using DRF's session authentication backend (cookie
>   csrftoken, sessionid) in another tab user opens in **domain-B**
>   classic django admin and is automatically authenticated?

Is it possible?